# Create tar file in parent of working directory

Tags: linux, tar

I am trying to create a tar file but not place it in the current working directory but rather the parent of whatever the current working dir is.
I've tried the -C option but with no success.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try like this

```
    $ tar -cvf ../filename.tar ToBeArchivedFolder
```

Make sure you are using lower case 'c' in the command line options

Comment: yeah I should clarify that I do not know the path of the current working directory. So that will work for the parent directory but how could I place the archive in, say the home directory.

Comment: To place in home directory $ tar -cvf /home/filename.tar ToBeArchivedFolder